# Troubles: JavaFX Webview + Windows8.1 + 1920x1080 = unusable small fonts

Tags: netbeans, webview, javafx

unfortunately i have some problems with my new notebook and javafx development.

Whenever i use a webview to display content in my program i'm getting really small and nearly unreadable fonts - now i'm not sure what exactly the problem is:

- Is it the new Win8.1 environment which is extremly bad for javaFX (+webView) development, or
- Is it the new notebook with 1920x1080 resolution on an 13" display which is way to much for a small screen, or
- Is it only a matter of configuration and i've overseen some basics :-)

i would really appreciate every possible suggestion

thanks :)

p.s.: I'm using JDK7 and NetBean 7.4 - i also tried JDK8 but that didn't change anything?!

Answer (score 2):

Apply the WebView [fontScaleProperty](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html#fontScaleProperty) to scale the text displayed in the WebView.

If you think it's an issue (e.g. the fontScaleProperty should default to some better value for your particular configuration), you might want to also take a screenshot (maybe even a digital photo of the laptop screen), and [log an issue in the JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).